# SwiftUI scale view without affecting geometry

Tags: swift, swiftui

Looking for a way to scale a view (screen) without affecting the underlying geometry.

So at the moment I have a SwiftUI view (ScaleViewTest) I've added a ZStack to it with a Rectangle background which is covering the whole view (ignoring safe area)

In my preview struct I am adding a scale modifier with a value of 0.99, which should scale the view to that factor proportionally... in theory.

What is actually happening is it is altering the internal view geometry, (in this case the internal view says, "We have only been given 99% of the screen to work with therefore, we don't have a safe area)

What I want to achieve is being able to scale the view without the internal view's geometry being.

I have tried:

- Using `GeometryReader` to get the `safeAreaInsets` but doesn't work because there is no safeArea.

Code pasted to provide reference.

```
struct ScaleViewTest: View {
    var body: some View {
      ZStack {
        Rectangle()
        .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.init(hexadecimal: "#005A65"), Color.init(hexadecimal: "#002D33")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
          .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

        Text("Hello, this is a new view")
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .font(.system(size: 22))

      }
    }
}

struct ScaleViewTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScaleViewTest()
          .scaleEffect(0.99)
    }
}
```

It's hard to make sense of what is happening, leave some comments if you need any other information. But an example of what I'm trying to achieve is like Airbnb, when you click on a listing you see the parent view scale down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any modifier *creates* new view, which is aligned in parent container with default rules, until explicitly specified.

So this one

```
    ScaleViewTest()
        .scaleEffect(0.99) // << new view
```

is similar to this one

```
    ScaleViewTest()
        .frame(height: 400) // << new view
```

probably it is agreed that it is strange to expect full-screen from the second one, so it is same for first.

Thus the solution to stretch resulting view to full screen is, obviously,

```
    ScaleViewTest()
      .scaleEffect(0.99)
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

**Update:** proposed solution - move scale inside via binding (manageable & animatable outside)

so in Preview

```
ScaleViewTest(scale: .constant(0.99))
```

gives

[image: demo]

```
struct ScaleViewTest: View {
    @Binding var scale: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
      ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.yellow]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))

        Text("Hello, this is a new view")
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .font(.system(size: 22))

      }
      .scaleEffect(scale)
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you still want to use safe area in ScaleViewTest? For example the text was at the top of the screen instead of the centre? I can't seem to get access to the safe area from geometry reader in that view

Comment: Cool! That makes sense. It was the order of operations that confused me.